# Firestore rules for query with where clause

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am building an Angular app which uses Google Firebase as a backend, and Firestore as a database.

**DISCLAIMER:** I'm providing a company-employee example since it's a well-known use-case, and it's much more concise this way than explaining my concrete domain. It's not a perfect analogy, though, so if it sounds slightly illogical, bear with me.

I have a `companies` Firestore collection, which holds an `employees` subcollection. I allow read/write permissions to any `company` only for its employees, and I allow it for ALL employees.

Any `user` can become an `employee` of a `company`, so I'm storing an `employeeUserIds` array on all `company` documents.

**[EDIT]:** You can find db structure [here](https://tree.nathanfriend.io/?s=(%27options!(%27fancy-%7EfullPath!false%7EtrailingSlash-%7ErootDot-)%7E0(%270%27%2F.s%2F(.)%2Fdocument*companie*2employee*users%27)%7Eversion!%271%27)*s%5Cn2-!true.database0source!2%20%20%0120.-*), since it was requested in documents. Keep in mind that each `company` holds an array of `uids` of all nested `employees`.

When fetching a `company` for a `user` with all `employees`, I use this query (*catchError* calls currently there for debug purposes):

```
getByUserId(userId: string): Observable<Company | null> {
    return this._afs.collection<CompanyDbModel>('companies',
        ref => ref.where('employeeUserIds', 'array-contains', userId))
        .valueChanges({idField: 'id'})
        .pipe(
            catchError(err => {
                console.log('in company', err);
                return of(null);
            }),
            map(res => res![0]),
            switchMap(companyDb => {
                return !!companyDb
                    ? this.getCompanyEmployees(companyDb.id).pipe(map(employees => /* mapping */))
                    : of(null);
            }),
            catchError(err => {
                console.log('in employees', err);
                return of(null);
            }),
            take(1)
        );
}
```

This worked until I added this to my security rules:

```
match /companies/{companyId}/{document=**} {
    allow read, update: if signedIn() && emailVerified() && userIsCompanyEmployee(companyId);
    allow create: if signedIn() && emailVerified() && documentIsNew(/companies);
}
```

Relevant functions below:

```
function company(companyId) {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/companies/$(companyId));
}

function userIsCompanyEmployee(companyId) {
    return userId() in company(companyId).data.employeeUserIds;
}

function documentIsNew(collectionPath) {
    let newDocId = request.resource.data.id;
    return !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(collectionPath)/$(newDocId));
}
```

`userId()` function simply returns `request.auth.uid`.

If you look at the two `catchError` calls in the first code block, the one that actually executes is the first one (`console.log('in company', err);`). My assumption is that I cannot execute the where clause, since it *can* contain companies that don't match my criteria.

If I'm right about the cause of the error – any help with securing this query? This is the only way I can access a `company` as a user, since I don't know which company a user works for in advance, and I can potentially have several of them in the future. I've searched online for a while now, but came up empty.

Comment: can you also show the structure of your db using [File structure type](https://tree.nathanfriend.io/)

Comment: I'm adding it to the question, although this part of the db really is as simple as described.